# z-index of hover tooltip with CSS

Tags: css, tooltip, z-index

I hover a thumbnail image using CSS-only:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#like_table td a{z-index:2;}
#like_table .tooltip
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#like_table .tooltip a
{
  z-index:2;
}
#like_table .tooltip span
{
  z-index:9999;
  display:none;
}
#like_table .tooltip:hover span
{
          position:absolute;
          display:block;
          top:1.5em;
          left:2em;
          border:1px solid black;
          background-color:white;
          padding:0.2em;
}
#like_table td .tooltip .tooltip_thumb{
            z-index:99999;
}
</style>

<table id='like_table' class='smallfont' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>
                    <div class='like_row'>
                        <a href='#user1' class='nul'>User 1</a> liked <a href='#link' class='tooltip'>forum post<span><img src='image.jpg' class='tooltip_thumb' alt='' /></span></a>
                        <span class='by_user'>by <a href='#user2' class='nul'>User 2</a></span>
                    </div>
                    </td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, the z-index on the span and the hover image does not seem to work.
The image is shown "below" the username (with class by_user), but above the normal text.

How can I make the overlay / tooltip show on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all your current `z-index` and just leave the `z-index: 9999` on `.tooltip`

Comment: On .tooltip, it didn't work. But it work when I added it to ".tooltip span". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your z-index will not work because all these items are not on the same level. They are all nested in each other. Z-index only works on elements on same level in DOM like this:

```
<div class="level1">
   <span class="level2"> 1 </span>
   <span class="level2"> 2 </span>
   <span class="level2"> 3 </span>
</div>
```

that will work if you set z-index on the spans, but if you put on  it will have no effect because it is "upper" element.

edit: and in your css you have written `.tooltip a` but you have no `<a>` in `.tooltip`, so you ment `a.tooltip` i suppose.

Comment: then what do I do if I want something on the same level to display on top? I want to display a tooltip over some other web elements and am not sure whether I should be moving the tooltip to a higher level (makes inheritance of css a pain) or whether there is another method I should use to force the tooltip to the top

Comment: There is no way to force element to be on the top of every other element on the page. To do so you should be very precise with all the z-indexes all over the page. I will recommend using a javascript plugin which is built on the fly every time you hover over an item. They create it on the first level of the DOM with calculated position and put very large z-index to make sure it overlaps every other element.