# How can I adjust the z-index of a tooltip for a Bootstrap form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add field validation to a "Contact Us" form using Bootstrap and a  validation library (a jQuery Plugin) called Validetta (http://lab.hasanaydogdu.com/validetta/).

After implementing the form and the validation, though, I am noticing a problem with the z-index of the tooltip that causes it to show up beneath the next form field.

If I were dealing with normal HTML and CSS, I think the answer would be a little more clear to me, but with Bootstrap, I do not know what sort of mysticism is afoot and am having trouble finding answers on how to solve this problem in the best-practices way.

[image: Z-Index Problem]

I know that Validetta is adding a `<SPAN>` after the form field and is applying a custom CSS class to it, which I can easily modify, override, or append.  I've also read, in other contexts, that this problem can be solved using a combination of `z-index` and `position` on the tooltip `SPAN` and one or more of its parent elements... but all of my quick tests and trials have not had the desired affect.

Here's the rendered HTML for the form field shown above:

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputFromName">Your Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFromName" name="fromName" placeholder="Your Name Here" data-validetta="required" data-vd-message-required="This field is required!">
  <span class="validetta-bubble validetta-bubble--bottom">This field is required!<br></span>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Refer this answer [Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386759/z-index-of-hover-tooltip-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

you may check the z-index attribute on **parent elements** of "validetta-bubble" ;
because z-index judge from parent to child, if a parent has a lower z-index while child elemtn has a higher this element's z-index finally work base on the parenet's
you may try to set form-group's z-index

```
.form-group {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
}
```

and set a higher on target like answer 1

```
.crazy-zindex {
  z-index: 10001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I found the answer to this question here: [z-index of hover tooltip with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386759/z-index-of-hover-tooltip-with-css)

The answer from **Панайот Толев** provided this example:

```html
<div class="level1">
   <span class="level2"> 1 </span>
   <span class="level2"> 2 </span>
   <span class="level2"> 3 </span>
</div>
```

So, to solve the problem, I wrapped each row of form elements in a div that specified a `z-index` in the `style` attribute.  As I went down the rows, I decreased the `z-index` value, like so:

```html
<div style="z-index: 23;"> .. </div>
<div style="z-index: 22;"> .. </div>
<div style="z-index: 21;"> .. </div>
```

This ensured that each row fell "behind" the one above, which allowed tool-tips to appear on top of the fields (and labels), rather than beneath them.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
When no other script solved my problem. Then I had used **parent** class as **data-container**.
For exp.

```
<ul id="responsivator">
    <li data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#responsivator" title="iPhone landscape Preview" >
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add a custom class like `crazy-zindex` (I'm sure you can come up with a better name) and a rule in the css for it.

HTML

```
<span class="validetta-bubble validetta-bubble--bottom crazy-zindex">This field is required!<br></span>
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

CSS

```
.crazy-zindex {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Its important to remember that CSS is cascading, so the last rule will overwrite anything above it, with this said, any overwrites you want to do to bootstrap you'll have to `link` that stylesheet after bootstrap. Or you can use `!important` but that's not good practice.

Comment: I've tried things along these lines; I added a `z-index: 10000` to the `validetta-bubble` class and verified, in Chrome inspector, that the `z-index` is not being overwritten.  I've also tried `!important`, just to see if it had an effect,. but it did not.  Based on other things I've read I think I need to apply a `position` attribute to the field, tooltip, form, divs, or something .. but have not, yet, managed to find the right combination.  Still, even though Validetta does not allow me to easily add an additional class, I will coerce one into the SPAN and try what you've suggested, exactly.

Comment: Ok, I verified that this doesn't work :( -- I used `$("SPAN.validetta-bubble").addClass("crazy-zindex");` to add the `crazy-zindex` class to the bubble after it is shown.  I also added the exact CSS snippet you suggested, above, to my CSS.  I then used Chrome inspector to verify that it was added and that the `z-index` was properly overridden to `10000`.  Nothing has changed and the tooltip still appears "beneath" the form field below it.